# Convolution theorem with respect to Laplace transforms

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I have recently been learning about Laplace transforms and how to use them for solving ODEs. I understand how to calculate and use both $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ however I am struggling to understand where the convolution theorem has come from, and what convolution is. My understanding is this:

Say we have two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ (which we will presume are real and continuous) we can say that:
$$\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=F(s),\,\mathcal{L}[g(t)]=G(s)$$
and we wish to find:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)G(s)]$$
we can use the fact that this is equal to:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)G(s)]=(f*g)(t)$$
where:
$$f*g=\int_0^tf(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$
Whilst this defines what convolution actually is, I do not see why this is the case or what the convolution of two functions represents outside of this use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the Laplace Transform of the convolution, $(f*g)(t)$.  We assume that $f$ and $g$ are causal functions (i.e., ,$f(t)=g(t)=0$ for $t<0$).  Proceeding, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\left(\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\right)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(\tau) \int_\tau^\infty e^{-st}g(t-\tau)\,dt\,d\tau\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(\tau) \int_0^\infty e^{-s(t+\tau)}g(t)\,dt\,d\tau\\\\
&=\left(\int_0^\infty f(\tau)  e^{-s\tau}\,d\tau\right)\left(\int_0^\infty g(t)  e^{-st}\,dt\right)\\\\
&=\mathscr{L}\{f\}(s) \mathscr{L}\{g\}(s) \\\\
&=F(s)G(s)\tag1
\end{align}$$

whereupon inversion of $(1)$ yields the coveted expression

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{FG\}(t)=(f*g)(t)$$

Comment: Great explanation thank you, I struggled to find this when I searched elsewhere and I did not think to simplify the integral  using the fact that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are non-zero for $t<0$. However could you explain how you got from $4$ to $5$ as I got: $$\int_0^t{f(\tau)e^{-s\tau}d\tau}\int_0^{\infty}{g(t)e^{-st}dt}$$

Comment: @HenryLee You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I've edited the typo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the ending still

Comment: How does $$\int_0^t g(t)e^{-st}dt=G(s)$$ and how can a limit contain the same variable as the integral

Comment: @HenryLee That was obviously another typo.  I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: so you obtained the new integral limits between lines $1$ and $2$ from the order of integration change?

Comment: @HenryLee Yes, the order of integration was changed.